# HTML page not loading using QWebView

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qwebview, qwebkit

I am trying to load one HTML file using QWebView, which contains a flash video. 
 But my webpage is not getting loaded at all. if I right click on the page , context menu is just displaying 
“load” button.

I am using QtSDK5.1 64bit on win7 64 bit machine.

NOTE :- 
 1. Same source code when I am compiling using QtSDK 4.8.1 32 bit it is working fine.
 2. I tried to install openssl libraries(copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in the same application folder) for win64 bit machine as well, but no luck.

Below mention is the code

```
QWebView m_pWyseWebView;
m_pWyseWebView.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
m_pWyseWebView.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
m_pWyseWebView.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavaEnabled, true);
m_pWyseWebView.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrivateBrowsingEnabled, true);
m_pWyseWebView.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);
m_pWyseWebView.settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::WebGLEnabled, true);
QString str = "<html><body style=\"background-color:rgb(0,0,0)\" topmargin=\"0\" leftmargin=\"0\"><embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"     src=\"http://z.cdn.turner.com/xslo/cvp/assets/container/2.0.4.0/cvp_main_container.swf\"     width=\"100%\"     height=\"100%\"  data=\"http://z.cdn.turner.com/xslo/cvp/assets/container/2.0.4.0/cvp_main_container.swf\"  name=\"cvp_1\"  id=\"cvp_1\"  type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"  PARAM=\"\"  quality=\"high\"  bgcolor=\"#000000\"  allowFullScreen=\"true\"  allowScriptAccess=\"always\"  wmode=\"direct\"  flashvars=\"context=vidEx&autostart=true&site=cnn&profile=desktop&domId=cvp_1&cvpSessionToken=KP156PURf6shHZ3PI72XS6ill\"></body></html>";
m_pWyseWebView.setHtml(str,QUrl("https://edition.cnn.com/video"));
m_pWyseWebView.setGeometry(50,50, 640, 480);
m_pWyseWebView.show();
```

Please help what needs to be installed extra on 64bit machine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy the openssl libs from a 32bit machine to a 64bit machine? Not quite clear from your wording. This might work if you have a 32bit Qt on your 64bit machine, but using 32bit openssl with a 64bit Qt won't work. You need get 64bit openssl libs.